# Как разложить массив в массиве Vue.js

Tags: javascript, массивы, vue.js

Всем привет, внутри таблицы мне нужно отрисовать данные подобного типа
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: исправьте картинки на обычный текст, с ним проще воспроизводить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вложенное поле является массивом, его так же можно использовать в `v-for`

```js
const {
  createApp
} = Vue

createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      data: [{
        id: 1,
        title: "Text",
        price: 20,
        image: [{
          path: "img1"
        }, {
          path: "img2"
        }, {
          path: "img3"
        }]
      }]
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="el in data" :key="el.id">
      <td> {{ el.title }} </td>
      <td> {{ el.price }} </td>
      <td>
        <span v-for="image in el.image">
          {{ image.path }}
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: А с key было лучше)

Comment: добавил key на верхнем уровне

Comment: @MrFylypenko благодарю за ответ, подскажите разве это не является плохой практикой?

Comment: @MrFylypenko в случае если будет много вложенных массивов, как это возможно было бы разложить?

Comment: @Bob, что именно должно являться плохой практикой и почему?

Comment: @MrFylypenko массив в массиве

Comment: @Oleggator скорее всего это даже хорошая практика, т.к. [пример вложенного v-for есть на сайте официальной документации](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#displaying-filtered-sorted-results) в самом внизу страницы